# Spectrum of a quotient map

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $T: X \rightarrow X$ be a linear automorphism acting on a complex Banach space $X$. Let $E \subset X$ be a closed $T$-invariant subspace ($TE = E$) that is not necessarily complemented in $X$.

Is there a relationship between the spectrum of the induced map on the quotient and that of $T$?